# В чем разница между PID и HANDLE процесса?

Tags: c++, windows, процесс

В чем между ними разница и что можно сделать с процессом имея либо PID либо HANDLE?

Comment: pid - линукс, handle - windows. Или нужно больше?

Comment: windows тоже имеет pid

Comment: речь про windows

Comment: HANDLE - идентификатор не только процессов, но и всех ресурсов. PID - номер процесса.

Comment: http://www.cyberforum.ru/cpp-beginners/thread634006.html тут обсуждают вопрос и есть код.

Comment: Хендлы могут наследоваться, а pid уникален и существует до окончания процесса, хендлы остаются даже после окончания процесса, пока не будут закрыты.

Comment: Выполните из командной строки команду tasklist. Увидите все pid процессов.

Comment: Зная Pid процесса, вы можете его убить.

Comment: @HasmikGaryaka TerminateProcess работает по хэндлу, а не по пиду.

Comment: PID определенно явлеятся номером процесса. Существует еще "псевдо-хэндл", который для текущего процесса равен -1. А хэндл модуля, получаемый через GetModuleHandle - базовый адрес модуля... Но это про модуль, не про процесс...

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов taskkill из командной строки.

Comment: @HasmikGaryaka а в результате убьют его все равно по хэндлу внутри taskkill

Answer (score 2):

PID — это Process ID (идентификатор процесса), он уникален в пределах системы, т.е. одновременно не существует двух процессов с одинаковыми PID. Используется для идентификации процесса извне.

HANDLE — условно, адрес, по которому хранится информация по процессу, например такая как: время запуска, имя файла, ассоциированного с процессом, и даже тот же самый PID. Будучи однажды получен, HANDLE требует закрытия через `CloseHandle()`. Используется внутри программы, нет особого смысла в передаче наружу. В общем случае, тип HANDLE может идентифицировать разные ресурсы, далеко не только процессы. В winnt.h [описан как](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751(v=vs.85).aspx) указатель на `void` (т.е. на любой тип):

```
typedef PVOID HANDLE;
```

Так как зная PID можно получить HANDLE и наоборот, сделать с процессом можно всё что угодно, но должны быть соответствующие привилегии.

Comment: Я бы ещё добавил, что HANDLE в WinAPI-программировании — просто синоним (непрозрачного) указателя на данные. Т. е. может быть HANDLE не только на процесс, но и на другие данные.

Comment: @VladD сделано.

Comment: Я наблюдал за Handle - в xp он кратен 4, Handle - номер обьекта в таблице хандлов.

Comment: @nick_n_a: Угу, [так и есть](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050121-00/?p=36633).